# The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**EDIT:** Turns out this is due to characters in the languages and characters such as i/u etc.

```
[HttpPost]  
        /*[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]*/
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var users = _userdb.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName); 
                if (users.Any())
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Username Already Exists.");
                    return View(model);
                }

                try
                {
                    if (model.IsAdmin == false)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, propertyValues: new
                        {
                            CellPhone = model.CellPhone,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            SocialNo = model.SocialNo,
                            Department_Id = model.DepartmentId
                        });


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, propertyValues: new
                        {
                            CellPhone = model.CellPhone,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            SocialNo  = model.SocialNo ,
                            Department_Id = 9999
                        });

                        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "admin"); 
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Departments", "Index");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I am getting this error and this is really not helpful. I just want to register a user.

Why am i getting this error?  Any idea?

Note that, `UserProfile` is getting the data but not the membership table.

Comment: Do you get an inner exception?

Comment: no inner exception and no information. it is ridiculous

Comment: Are you capturing the exception in the `catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)` block? You should be able to track where this comes from. It's generally related to OAuth and part of the template-generated Accounts controller code.

Comment: I just edited, it is actually related to a turkish character, ie: database collation etc.

Comment: I think it will be helpfull for you, try to do this;

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843022/asp-net-simple-membership-provider/15093536#15093536][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843022/asp-net-simple-membership-provider/15093536#15093536